# Al clonar la clase Request y modificar parametro json , se modifica la clase original

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Realizando peticiones web con distintos formatos para probar una Api , obtuve una devolucion  inesperada relacionada con la clonacion de Request:

Al enviar parámetros por  body en formato json  y modificarlos  en un nuevo objeto clonado , estas se modifican en el objeto Request original:

```
  //{"json":"resultado"}
  $clone = clone $request;
  $clone->merge(['json'=>'resultado modificado']);
  echo " clon : $clone->json , original : $request->json";
```

Resultado esperado: clon : resultado modificado , original : resultado

Resultado obtenido: clon : resultado modificado , original : resultado modificado

Este efecto pasa solamente ocurre por json , al enviar los datos form o por query,la devolución es la esperada.

La forma de clonar es indiferente , recibo los mismo resultados utilizando `$request->duplicate()`.

Deduzco que  ocurre por que las variables json de request estan siendo reverenciadas y al clonar, este copia las referencias.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar este efecto?¿por que ocurre únicamente con las peticiones json?.

Edicion1: utilizando

```
//{"json":"result"}
  $clone = clone $request->duplicate();
  dump($request->all());
  $clone->merge(['json'=>'resultado modificado']);
  dump($clone->all());
  dump($request->all());
```

Recibo la siguiente respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al modificar el clon la devolución del request cambia.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que pasa si en vez de `echo " clon : $clone->json , original : $request->json";` pones `dump($clone->all())`?

Comment: con dump($clone->all()) recibo la misma respuesta tanto del clon como del request